# aws signed url cached in browser? or somewhere?

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, caching, amazon-s3, self-signed

I am working with aws sdk with js.  Recently I am using signed url to protect user content after they uploaded the files.
I understand that the expire time can be set by seconds and default is 3600 as mentioned in documentation.

I have created the signed url in return successfully.  I have my code below

```
const adapter = require('skipper-better-s3')({
    adapter: require('skipper-better-s3'),
    key: key,
    secret: secret_key,
    saveAs: path,
    bucket: bucket,
    s3params: {
      ACL: 'public-read'
    },
  })

adapter.url('getObject', { s3params: { Key, Expires: 10 } });
```

Things does work fine, but the problem I am having now which I am not too sure what caused it is that for example,  if I use chrome to open up the signed url, I can keep on using the signed url even after 10 seconds which is the `Expires` I set but that is IF I opened the url once already.

Let's say if I generated the signed url, if I did not open the url within the 10 seconds, I open it then I will get blocked which is totally correct BUT if I opened the url within the 10 seconds, then even after 10 minutes I am still able to re-use that url, if I use new tab / new window, I still can open it with that url.  But if I use a private / congnito window then I would be blocked or if I use a different browser then I will get blocked.

So what is causing the browser to keep on able to open that url though, even if with new tab or new window.  I want to disable this as I do not want the cache being there and wants it to expire at the same time.

Hopefully my explanation is clear enough.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions / advices.

Comment: you can check this https://advancedweb.hu/2019/06/04/cacheable_signed_urls/